# Filtering WP query by ACF relationship

Tags: wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. I have a custom post type called "Námskeið". In that I have a relationship field where I connect a certain page to the specific course (námskeið). I then use that to display the relevant courses in a sidebar like this:

```
$namskeid = new WP_query(array(

    'posts_per_page' => '6',
    'post_type' => 'namskeid',
    'meta_type' => DATE,
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'  => 'course_date',

    'meta_query' => array(

        array (
            'key' => 'course_type_display',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => get_the_ID( 180 )
        ))
));
```

It works perfectly. I wanted to use the same logic to filter out courses by relationship in another page. What I want to create is a button where each type of course can be displayed separately or all of them together, depending on the users wishes. For some reason this exact code doesn't display anything in another page. I use a different query name: $namskeidInfo.

I've been reading a lot about $_GET function to use a taxonomy to filter the results so I'm wondering if I should just not use the relationship field in ACF bur rather custom taxonomy. In that case, what is the best way of achieving this?

Please bear with me, I'm pretty new to this game and am trying my best to understand the logic and creating the best code possible.

Answer (score 0):

in function get_the_ID() we do not pass the id:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

Try:

```
$namskeid = new WP_query(array(

'posts_per_page' => '6',
'post_type' => 'namskeid',
'meta_type' => DATE,
'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_key'  => 'course_date',

'meta_query' => array(

    array (
        'key' => 'course_type_display',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        'value' => 180
    )) 
));
```

more about is in ACF site https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/